# Is it possible to customize the message Azure Pipelines Bot sends in MS Teams?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, microsoft-teams

Is there a way to customize the message e.g. send custom variables?

[image]

Comment: Please take a look at [Customize Azure Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/customize-pipeline?view=azure-devops), Once you customize it Bot will send you updated card.

Comment: Does this require a .yaml file or is it possible with the classic UI designer for pipelines?

Comment: It reuquires configuration in .yaml file only.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding. I want to know whether it is possible to change the message the bot is sending. Right now there are following variables in the message: Build Pipeline, Branch, Requested for, Duration. Is it possible to add custom fields to the message, for example: Repository, Project or more?

Comment: You can't customize the inbuilt card sent by Bot which is configured for Azure Pipeline However you can set up your own Azure pipeline with your suitable custom variable